# Android Studio does not work with read-only shared Android Sdk

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3, android-studio-2.3

With Android Studio 2.3 it seems to be impossible to use a shared and therefore read-only SDK installation.

```
# pwd
/opt
# chmod -R a+r Android android-studio
# find Android -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
# find android-studio -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
# su other
$ export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/Android/Sdk
$ touch /opt/Android/Sdk/test
touch: cannot touch '/opt/Android/Sdk/test': Permission denied
/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Studio starts nicely but wants to download the Sdk (ANDROID_SDK_ROOT) is ignored. But anyway, we can try to set it in the SDK-Manager, but that does not work as the location is read-only (I can understand that a "Manager" does not want a read-only location). Then there is the possibility to
"Configure, Project Defaults, Project Structure" and there the entry "Android SDK Location to /opt/Android/Sdk which is accepted. And this works for existing projects. But when starting a new project I see the wizard abort with the message that the Sdk Location is not writable.

Copying an empty project and starting from there works. Ubuntu 16.04.3, Oracle Jdk 1.8. Fresh Android Studio 2.3.3.

Comment: I use a read-only SDK all the time with Android Studio 2.3.3 on Ubuntu. You might want to edit your question and provide **much more detailed explanations** of your symptoms.

Comment: thanks, I tried to edit an be more specific

Comment: I do not know what to tell you. The Android Studio directory probably needs to be read-write. But I have my Android SDK in `/opt/android-sdk-linux/`, with permissions set to 644, and I do not have a problem with the new-project wizard. There is little question that Android Studio is expecting a read-write SDK directory, but other than for SDK updates, I have not had a problem with recent Studio versions in having the SDK directory be read-only.

Comment: ok - thanks anyway, I dig deeper and try to find in the logs where exactly it hangs...

Comment: I tried it on two different machines and it worked there. The only difference was /dev/kvm enablement on the machines. And I know, that that has really *nothing* to do with the "create project" wizard. Still, enabling kvm for all users, reboot, works.... whatever...

Comment: That is very strange. But, I am glad that it is now working for you!